# Using Picture as split line between upper and lower wesite content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a coloured picture like a split horizontal line between upper paragraph content and lower paragraph content in my webpage. But the problem is that although I have set picture as background for .hr class in CSS code, a grey line still appears above the picture-split-line. How can I remove the line above the picture?

Html I am using is below:

```
<p>
  upper content upper content upper content upper content upper content upper content
</p>

<div class="hr">
  <hr />
</div>

<p>
 lower content lower content lower content lower content lower content lower content</p>
```

Here is my css:

```
div.hr {
    background: #fff url(image.png) repeat scroll center; 
    height: 10px
    }
```

I have tried altering `div.hr` properties to overlap the line but nothing works. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep the `<hr>` element, because the `div.hr` is currently acting as a horizontal rule.

```
<div class="hr"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually I can't remove hr because I need it there when the image is not loaded in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<hr />` from your code. The line above your image is due to the `<hr />`.

```
<p> upper content upper content upper content upper content upper content upper content </p> 

<div class="hr"> 
</div> 

<p> lower content lower content lower content lower content lower content lower content</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. If I remove hr then there will be nothing between the paragraph I images/css are off in a browser or if its not loaded due to slow connection.

Comment: Ok then go with the TheNoble-Coder's answer. But try to explain these things in your question for our better understanding. Thank you.